# Spss syntax how to list values with labels

Tags: list, syntax, label, spss

I like using the list command in spss but it can get confusing when it prints in the output the number that corresponds to the category and not the label.

For example:

```
Data list list
/ id var1 var2.
BEGIN DATA.
1, 2, 2
2, 2, 2
3, 1, 1
END DATA.
LIST.
VALUE LABELS VAR1 1 'YES' 2 'NO'.
VALUE LABELS VAR2 1 'YES' 2 'NO'.
LIST.
```

The output of LIST is the same after I attach value labels. I would like to print the value labels, rather than the value itself
Any help will be very appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [`LIST`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_list_overview.htm) command, I don't believe there to be a way to control for this, printing values vs. labels.

However you could [`SUMMARIZE`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_summarize.htm) (`Analyze--> Reports-->Case Summaries...`) which yields results in conventional table format and has greater degree of options. Therefore you could then control for printing values vs. labels as you desire. Typically this would be done using [`SET TNUMBERS`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_set_onumbers_ovars_tnumbers_tvars.htm). You could use `TVARS` also for controlling variable names vs. labels, for example too. This is the case for all and any table output procedure.

```
PRESERVE.
SET TVARS=LABELS TNUMBERS=LABELS.
SUMMARIZE
  /TABLES=ALL
  /FORMAT=VALIDLIST NOCASENUM TOTAL LIMIT=100
  /TITLE='CASE SUMMARIES'
  /MISSING=VARIABLE
  /CELLS=COUNT.
RESTORE.
```

[`PRESERVE`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_preserve.htm) and [`RESTORE`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_restore.htm) above simply (as it says on the tin) preserve the setting before any (`SET`) changes are made and then restore once completed.

Comment: Thank you * 1.000.000 you have saved me so much time